# How to continuously poll mpd for currently played song and write result to a file?

Tags: mpd

The only thing i need to extract from mpd is the currently played song/track. I have to ensure this always is up to date in the output file.

Comment: What format do you want the information about the currently-played song to appear in? How are you talking to the server? Are you using `mpc`, or a library like `ruby-mpd`?

Comment: The format only need to be as simple as Artist - Songname. Currently im only using the mpd module in ampache (localplay). I can certainly install whatever client/module that is most practical to extract this information from mpd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install [mpc](http://www.musicpd.org/clients/mpc/) then you can do the following:

```sh
mpc idle player # block until the player changes songs
mpc current     # outputs "Artist Name - Song Name" onto stdout
```

Do those in a loop, and output the result of `current` into a file, and you're done!

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
  mpc current > current_song.txt
  mpc idle player
done
```

---

The full list of what you can `idle` for is on the MPD command reference:
http://www.musicpd.org/doc/protocol/command_reference.html#status_commands

Comment: Just a note for anyone like me who tried using this to record number of times a track was played, it won't work: `mpc idle player` fires not only for current song changes, but also when player is paused and unpaused.